# How can I scale up findOneAndUpdate in mongoose/mongodb for 5 million updates?

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a backend with these: nodejs, mongoose, mongodb, ironmq. And there is another app (a python FTP server) which is used as a data source.

The system, more or less, works like this:

- User uploads a csv dump of data (almost 3 million entries) to the FTP server (this happens periodically, once every 24 hrs)
- The FTP server parses the data, and pushes to a IronMQ queue in batches (of 2000) synchronously. I'm doing the batching here to optimize for memory
- Another app (nodejs) keeps polling this queue for the data, 100 messages (which is the maximum number allowed) every 10 seconds, works on this data and then updates my db (using `findOneAndUpdate` for each message). I have 5 of these apps running.

Now there aren't any glaring issues with this setup except for the time taken for the whole operation to complete. It takes almost 2 hours for the parsed data to be pushed to the MQ completely, but this is not much of a problem since its being done in batches. The actual problem comes with the **"saving/updating to db"** part.

On an average, 20-24K entries are updated in the db every hour. But since I have 3 million entries, this is taking more than 24 hrs (which doesn't work since the files on FTP gets refreshed every 24 hrs and the data will be used to perform certain operations in other parts of my app).

I'm not exactly sure how to go on from here, but I have a couple of questions.

- Can my above approach be considered optimal/efficient? Or what can be improved?
- How can I reduce the time taken for the whole update operation either via db or by changing the design?
- Is mongodb considered good for this case, or are there any better alternatives?

It would be awesome if you can provide some help on this. Please do let me know in case you guys need more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimise your updates by using the Bulk API methods which are very efficient as they allow you to send many update operations within a single request (as a batch) to the server.
Consider the following examples which demonstrate this approach for different MongoDB versions:

Suppose your nodejs apps polls the messages data to a list and for Mongoose versions `>=4.3.0` which support MongoDB Server `3.2.x`, you can use **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** for updating the collection as:

```
var bulkUpdateCallback = function(err, r){
        console.log(r.matchedCount);
        console.log(r.modifiedCount);
    },
    operations = []; // Initialise the bulk operations array

messages.forEach(function (msg) { 
    operations.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": msg._id } ,              
            "update": { "$set": { "value": msg.value } } // example update operation
        }
    });

    // Send once in 500 requests only
    if (operations.length % 500 === 0 ) {
        Model.collection.bulkWrite(
            operations, 
            { "ordered": true, w: 1 }, 
            bulkUpdateCallback
        ); 
        operations = [];
    }    
});

// Get the underlying collection via the native node.js driver collection object
Model.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { "ordered": true, w: 1 }, bulkUpdateCallback);
```

In the above, you initialise your update operations array and limit the operations to batches of 500. The reason of choosing a lower value than the default batch limit of 1000 is generally a controlled choice. As noted in the documentation there, MongoDB by default will send to the [server in batches of 1000 operations at a time at maximum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size) and there is no guarantee that makes sure that these default 1000 operations requests actually fit under the [16MB BSON limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). So you would still need to be on the "safe" side and impose a lower batch size that you can only effectively manage so that it totals less than the data limit in size when sending to the server.

---

If you are using older versions of Mongoose `~3.8.8, ~3.8.22, 4.x` which support MongoDB Server `>=2.6.x`, you could use the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/bulk-write-operations/)** API as follows

```
var bulk = Model.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    bulkUpdateCallback = function(err, r){
        console.log(r.matchedCount);
        console.log(r.modifiedCount);
    },
    counter = 0;

messages.forEach(function(msg) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": msg._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "value": msg.value }
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(function(err, r) {
           // do something with the result
           bulk = Model.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
           counter = 0;
        });
    }
});

// Catch any docs in the queue under or over the 500's
if (counter > 0) {
    bulk.execute(bulkUpdateCallback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try and implement this.